# Cast base object to derived class

Tags: java

I have two classes:

```
class Base {

  public String name;

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }


}

class Derived extends Base {

  public String getValue() {
    return name + " foo";
  }

}
```

And an object created:

```
Base foo = new Base();
foo.setName("John");

Derived bar = (Derived) foo;
```

This simple example gives `ClassCastException` exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Base cannot be cast to Derived
```

Is it possible somehow to extend existing object with extra read-only methods ?

Comment: `Foo` ? Where is `Foo` defined ?Your example doesn't seem consistent

Comment: No, it's not possible. You can't change the type of an object at runtime (which is what you're attempting).

Comment: @DenysSéguret Oh my, sorry. Edited.

Comment: Well. So no, you can't do that. There's no class mutation in java.

Comment: Delegation or composition is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `Base foo = new Base();` you're saying that you have a Cat, but all of the sudden you're trying to convert it to Persian cat, which would have succeeded, if all the cats were Persian ones. This is not true and that's why you get a `ClassCastException`.

You have to do:

```
Base foo = new Derived();
```

Answer (score 2):

> Cast base object to derived class

You can't cast *objects*, you can only cast *references*. The object is unchanged either way.

If you create a `Base` (`new Base`), that's all you have. You can't then call your reference to it a `Derived` because it *isn't* a `Derived`, it's a `Base`. (Which is why you get the `ClassCastException`: At runtime, the JVM checks what you're referring to to make sure it really can be referred to that way.)

The other direction works:

```
Derived d = new Derived();
Base b = d;
```

...because the object that `d` refers to is a `Derived`, and `Derived` extends `Base`, meaning that it has an ***is a*** relationship with `Base`: All `Derived` objects are also `Base` objects.

The converse is not true: All `Base` objects are **not** `Derived` objects. Attempts to treat them as though they were (by casting references) will fail.

You can define a `Derived` constructor that accepts a `Base` and copies its state as part of building a new object. But you can't change the type of the actual object; you have to create a *new* object with equivalent state.

Answer (score 1):

**Just pretend:**

```
Derived bar = (Derived) foo;
```

worked!!!

`class Base` doesn't have the  `getValue()` method, so

```
Base foo = new Base();
```

`foo`  does't have it.

But as bar is a reference of `class Derived` so you can call `bar.getValue()`.
So, if you call `bar.getValue()` what will happen (there is no any `getValue()` in `bar`) .?

The basic concept is all child class can be treated as a Parent class. Because child class have almost  everything which the parent class have.

But as you can add anything later on child class so Parent class object  can't be casted to a child class object.

**extend existing object**
From the basic of `OOP` `object` is an instance (real thing)  created form a `Class` (the blue print). If there is a way then it's gonna violate the basic rule.

Answer (score 0):

1. The core concept of ObjectOrientation is not derivation (or inheritance) but abstraction. It means: If you want that all of your derived Types (classes) have an operation 'genName()' then it is a very good and core idea to have the class `Base` with this feature. To invoke this method for all of your objects based on class `Base`, you can use the

   `Base ref = (Base)anyDerivedObject;
   ref.getName();`

Thas is a *downcast*. The compiler checks whether the downcast is possible. It never throws a ClassCastException if `Base` is really a Base class.

2. A second fundamental property of ObjectOrientation are virtual operations (methods). It means the derived class can implement the

`@Override public String getValue() {
   return name + " foo";
}`

Please use the `@Override` annotation in Java for a obvious and safe programming style. If you invoke

```
ref = getName();
```

the derived operation of Derived is invoked if the object which is referred by 'ref' is an instance of 'Derived'. That is done with the *virtual table* or *dispatch table* which is also present in Java (usual known from C++).

3. An *upcast* is:

`Derived ref2 = (Derived)ref;`

whereby the type of `ref` is `Base`, following the example above. The Java-compiler checks whether or not 'Derived' is derived from the type of 'ref', from 'Base'. If it isn't so the compiler forces an error. But if the references are related, the compiler cannot know whether the referenced object is proper. Therefore

```
Derived bar = (Derived) foo;
```

from the introducing example fails. The referenced object is not instanceof Derived. That can be only detect on runtime, not on compiletime.

4. Consider that all Variables in Java are references, never objects itself (excluding the 7 basic types int, short, char etc.). Objects (instances) in Java are always located in the heap and they are referenced in the operations. That is a fundamental concept of Java for safe programming. In C++ there are programming errors possible, which are difficult to find. The calculation time overhead for this concept is not so far.